# paytm_allinone_react-native payment fail in production mode

Tags: javascript, react-native, production, paytm

I am trying to integrate paytm in react native. In stagging mode all works fine. but when I change url to production mode and isStagging to false. then its not working and paytm screen is showing like "You lost in space" please help. thank you..

```
callbackUrl: "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=",
      isStaging: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are using production mid and the initiate transaction API is also being used in Production mode. If you are using the correct credentials then please raise a query on Paytm developer support